# Dog strange behavior before pooping

Tags: dogs, behavior, health, defecation

My dog is a shiba. He is now 16 months old. We live in a hot region in Brazil. This is our first pet, therefore we don't know how to address many suspicious behaviors. Unfortunately, some of these symptoms have lasted for most of his life now, and the vets we have seen so far in the city were unable to effectively help us. The symptoms I'm talking about are related to pooping. He only poops during walks.

These two symptoms have lasted for most of his life now:

- He always takes a long time, that is, he seems to need to walk a lot, before he can seem to be able to poop.
- For most of the minutes before pooping, he gets agitated, like he needs desperately to get free of some pain --- even though this lasts!... as I said, he takes time!

The next two symptoms have occurred before (not always), but are especially strong lately (for many weeks now), making me even more concerned:

- Immediately after pooping, he vigorously licks his anus.
- While walking, he suddenly (very suddenly) sits down with his anus on the ground, or walks strangely with his anus down (a little, not touching the ground), as if something suddenly started to ache.

So what about his feces? They have (almost) never been hard and dry --- rather the contrary: they used to be (seemingly unhealthy) soft most times. This has changed a few weeks ago, after a major dietary change (we are trying things out): before, he used to eat raw meat exclusively; then he started to be fed just cooked meat, rice and potatoes. After that change, his feces seem to be always healthy (neither hard nor soft). However, that dietary change didn't seem to affect the aforementioned symptoms. Not yet.

What could be the problem here?

Answer (score 1):

Might be the anal glands. They might be overfilled or agitated. Nothing to worry about, just a short visit to the vet.

Normally they should be emptied while pooping, but there might have been not enough pressure applied.